# How to understand eps (Error bound) in Nearest neighbor search

Tags: r, math, nearest-neighbor

Im using **nn2** function in package **RANN** to find nearest neighbors to a GPS point within a radius of 0.00001 (if understand it correctly within **around** ~1.11 m).

This function also accepts **eps** error as input.

**Default of 0.0** implies exact nearest neighbor search.

Can I understand eps error in meter measurements?

How does eps influences the amount of found neighbors or the search distance ?

Comment: The [`RANN` manual](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RANN/RANN.pdf) directs you to the [ANN Programming Manual](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~mount/ANN/Files/1.1.2/ANNmanual_1.1.pdf), where CTRL-F "error bound", first hit, gives you the explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [ANN Programming Manual](http://www.cs.umd.edu/%7Emount/ANN/Files/1.1.2/ANNmanual_1.1.pdf) (pointed at by the RANN manual):

> Optionally, a real value `eps ≥ 0` may be supplied. If so, then the *i-th* nearest neighbor is a `(1+eps)`
> approximation to the true *i-th* nearest neighbor. That is, the true (not squared) distance to
> this point may exceed the true distance to the real *i-th* nearest neighbor of `q` by a factor of
> `(1 + eps)`. If `eps` is omitted then nearest neighbors are computed exactly.

Comment: Thank you. But how would it transfer for example in meters

Comment: (1+eps) is a scaling factor, as explained in the manual. So, if eps=0.01, the distance may exceed the true distance by 1.01, that is 1%. Does this help?